# How can I close a jquery q tip balloon after some seconds automatically?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using qtip plug in to show balloon conversation on my page. i can load the balloon, but i am not seeing any option to close it automatically after some seconds.

This is how i am using qtip -

```
 $('#ShowBalloon')
      .click(function()
      {
         if($("#content a").data("qtip")) $("#content a").qtip("destroy");

         $("#content a").html("") // Set the links HTML to the current opposite corner
            .qtip({
               content: { text: 'You have 1 new message.' },
               position: {
                  corner: {
                     tooltip: 'bottomRight',
                     target: 'topRight'
                  }
               },
               show: {
                  when: false, 
                  ready: true,
                  effect: { type: 'fade' },
                  length: 2000
               },
               hide: { when: 'inactive', delay: 1000 },
               style: {
                  border: {
                     width: 1,
                     radius: 7,
                     color : "#00AFF0"
                  },
                  title: { 'color': 'red', 'overflow': 'hidden' },
                  width: 300,
                  color:'White',
                  background: '#00AFF0',
                  padding: 10, 
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  tip: true, 
               }
            });

      });
```

Comment: hide: { when: 'inactive', delay: 1000 } doesn't work?

Comment: @Bouillou : no it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried : hide: { when: { event: 'inactive' }, delay: 2000 } instead?